# Detect android notifications -- Without an AccessibilityService

Tags: android, notifications, root

I'm developing an android application designed for root phones. The intent is to use a text to voice API to read the notification out to the user. I'd like for it to require minimal to no configuration, which an AccessibilityService would hinder.

So, what I'm looking for: Is there a way to detect new notifications and their contents, other than using an AccessibilityService(or programatically enable/set up the AccessibilityService)? Even if the method would require root to perform(like, in windows, you could "hook" a function from an application, intercepting its call. is there something I could "hook" in the NotificationManager service to do this?).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is...no. Notifications are not accessible (unless you use an AccessibilityService). There is no way to programatically enable an AccessibilityService (if there was this would be a HUGE security breach on the part of Android phones).